# JSON like access path validation

Tags: java, json, regex

Hello,
I would like to parse a path to the element of JSON document in Java. I tried to create some regex but unfortunately it is not working.

First part of the path is always a string with char from group *([A-Za-z0-9]*)*, then we can access to nested elements by dot notation or by using square bracket (just like in JavaScript).

My regexp:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]*)([((\[['"])(.+)(['"]\]))|([.][^.\[\]]+)])*
```

Few examples of correct paths:

```
abc123.test['test1']
abc123["test"]['test1'].key2
abc123["keyWithEscapedBracket\[\]"].abc
```

Incorrect paths could looks like below:

```
abc[sda]
abc["wrong[Key"]
abc.["dotBeforeOpeningBracket"]
```

I spent a lot of time on this and finally stucked in place. Maybe there is a better solution than making a regex or exists library that parse and validate a'la JSON paths in Java?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/DCNQzU/1).

Comment: you can create your regex try:http://buildregex.com/

Comment: Thank you Wiktor for response. It is not working, if there will be some next nesting levels after brackets, it not matching anymore, e.g. abc["test1"].test2["sdas\\["].test